# Как отобразить элементы во внешнем списке в яндекс картах?

Tags: yandex-maps-api, яндекс-карты, yandex-maps-jsapi

Есть код https://jsfiddle.net/satantx/97k470hr/

Сейчас в строке поиска выведен город Владимир. К нему привязаны 2 элемента. Как их показать в списке справа, и чтобы можно было бы нажать на элемент в списке и центр карты сместился к этому адресу.

```
<ul>
    <li>Тут пункт 3</li>
    <li>Тут пункт 4</li>
</ul>
```

Спасибо

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, свой вопрос. Сейчас код по ссылке уже делает всё, что описано в вопросе.

Comment: Уже сделал всё) Не знаю как закрыть тему

Comment: Выложите, пожалуйста, решение (можно ответить на свой же вопрос), чтобы другие пользователи тоже узнали отгадку)